# How to redefine what is "Now" in Apache Superset filter?

Tags: filter, apache-superset

I'm trying to set a filter box, relative to a column from my database, rather than relative to the current time. For example, I'm displaying 'last update time' in a dashboard, and I have a filter. The user should be able to select the date from the filter, relative to that 'last update time'.

For example: today is the 3rd of May. Last update time is 1st of May. When I select Last day, I want that Last day to be the 1st of May, and not today (3rd of May).

[image: Example]

Is there a way to do that? I fiddled around with the filter box and JSON metadata, but couldn't find anything useful.